# How to make “Ctrl + L” to clear screen in ksh under Red hat linux?

Tags: rhel, ksh, putty

I am using putty to connect to the Red hat linux server. My shell under linux in Korn shell. I am used to clearing screen with the "Ctrl + l " combination. Some how this combination is not working under Ksh. If I type "`ctrl + l` " in ksh, it takes me to the new line.

I tried

```
alias "^L"=clear
```

still same result.

I also tried

```
bind -m '^L'=clear'^J'
```

but it says bind command not found. I can not install anything new on the machine.

Could you please advise how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What flavor of ksh are you using? mksh, ksh93....? I suppose you took those commands from here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10614/adding-ctrl-l-as-clear-hotkey-in-openbsds-ksh . OpenBSD's ksh might be (I don't know, to be honest) based on a different "flavor" of ksh than Redhat's, so what works in OpenBSD might or might not work in Redhat.

Comment: My korn shell is under "/bin/ksh". Yes OpenBSD might no work. I am interested to know what might work in Redhat. Also what is causing ^L to put newline.May be if I am able to find that binding, I can change it, just a thought

Comment: Why don't you use bash instead? Bash is part of the standard Red Hat installation, you wouldn't need to install anything.

Comment: Hi Gilles, the project requirement is for Korn shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red Hat provides "ksh-93", which does not have a `bind` command.  It provides something called `KEYBD`, which is triggered via a special `trap` function.  According to the manual page, that can be used to modify the *Emacs Editing Mode*.

The example at *[[Korn Shell] Fixing Home, End, pgup, pgdown, and delete keys](https://nixers.net/showthread.php?tid=19)*  is a useful starting point for showing how to make `^L` clear the screen.  By default, <kbd>meta</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (`^[^L`) is bound to the clear-screen function, while plain `^L` is just the next-line which you would like to change:

```
   ^L        Line feed and print current line.
   M-^L      Clear the screen.
```

Adding just one line to the example does what was asked:

```
set -o emacs

keybd_trap () {
  case ${.sh.edchar} in
    $'\f')    .sh.edchar=$'\e\f';;  # clear-screen (THIS QUESTION)
    $'\e[1~') .sh.edchar=$'\001';;  # Home = beginning-of-line
    $'\e[4~') .sh.edchar=$'\005';;  # End = end-of-line
    $'\e[5~') .sh.edchar=$'\e>';;   # PgUp = history-previous
    $'\e[6~') .sh.edchar=$'\e<';;   # PgDn = history-next
    $'\e[3~') .sh.edchar=$'\004';;  # Delete = delete-char
  esac
}
trap keybd_trap KEYBD
```

For whatever reason, vi-mode is far less capable in `ksh`.

The documentation is vague on how keys are actually mapped to functions. For this instance the feature is implemented in `src/cmd/ksh93/edit/emacs.c` as part of a switch/case statement:

```
#ifdef _cmd_tput
                case cntl('L'): /* clear screen */
                        sh_trap("tput clear", 0);
                        draw(ep,REFRESH);
                        return(-1);
#endif
```

within the escape function (i.e., handling "meta"). So it is built-in behavior that can be customizedksh.

Further reading:

- [KSH-93: Frequently Asked Questions](http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html)

```
Q4. How is keybinding done?
A4. ksh93 provides a KEYBD trap that gets executed whenever a key
    is entered from the keyboard.  Using this trap, and the associate
    array feature of ksh93, a keybind function can easily be written
    which will map any entered key sequence to another key sequence.
```

- [10.3. Customizing the Editing Modes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch10_03.htm) (Learning the Korn Shell)

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas Dickey for your detailed explanation. +1 and accepting this answer. Sorry I did not get chance to login to stackoverflow after putting the question. Thanks again :)